# How can I get IntelliJ to recognize Apex literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, apex, string-interpolation

Say I have a script in an Apex page, and in the script are literals denoted with `{! ... }`. How can I configure IntelliJ (with Jetforcer) to see them and not flag them with *Unterminated statement* warnings?

```
someJsVar= {!someApexVar}.toFixed(99);
```

[image]

Comment: IDEA provides no Apex support, and there is no way to teach it to accept Apex literals in JS. Jetforcer plugin authors have to take care of this. I can only suggest turning syntax highlighting off for such files to avoid syntax errors... This can be done using Hector icon in the lower right corner: open your file in editor, click the Hector icon and then move the slider to change the *Highlighting level* to *None*. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html. You will likely need to reopen the project to get the highlighting updated.

Comment: BTW, did you try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10253-illuminated-cloud-2 plugin? as far as I can see from https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/salesforce-development-plugins-part-1-illuminated-cloud/, Illuminated Cloud 2 extends IDEA HTML, JavaScript, and CSS editors with some Salesforce stuff

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into Illuminated Cloud, but I wonder if it'll conflict with Jetforcer at all.